# Why two sets of equal-spaced points of a circle are identical when relatively prime?

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory

Consider the two sets of M numbers given by $W^k$ , $ 0\leq k\leq M-1 $ and $ W^{kL} $, $ 0\leq k\leq M-1 $ where $ W = e^{-2j\pi/M} $. Show that these two sets are identical.

It is true for the small numbers. But how to prove it truth?(Without induction) What theorem is behind in this phenomenon? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me outline the idea leaving the proofs as an exercise. Let $$U = \{W^k : 0 \leq k \leq M - 1\},$$ where $W = e^{2\pi i /M}$. Let $$U^L = \{z^L : z \in U\}.$$

If you are not familiar with the language of groups, just recall that:

> If $L$ and $M$ are relatively prime, then there exist $r, s \in \mathbf Z$ such that $$Lr + Ms = 1$$

Conclude that:

> $W^k \in U^L$, for every $0 \leq k \leq M - 1$.

*Hint: $W^k= W^{kLr + kMs} = e^{2\pi i (kLr + kMs)/M} = \dots$*

Therefore,

> $U = U^L$

*Hint: count how many elements each set has*

---

---

If you are familiar with the language of groups, regard $U$ as a subgroup of $\mathbf C^\times$.

> $U$ is isomorphic to $\mathbf Z /M\mathbf Z$

*Hint: consider the map $\varphi: \mathbf Z \rightarrow U$ given by $\varphi(k) = W^k$.*

Under the above isomorphism, the set $$U^L = \{z^L : z \in U\}$$ is identified with $$L\mathbf Z/M \mathbf Z = \{ Lr + M \mathbf Z : r \in \mathbf Z\}.$$

> If $L$ and $M$ are relatively prime, then there exists $r \in \mathbf Z$ such that $$Lr \equiv 1 \mod M$$

*Hint: there exist integers $r$ and $s$ such that $Lr + Ms = 1$.*

Conclude that

> If $L$ and $M$ are relatively prime, then $$L\mathbf Z/M \mathbf Z = \mathbf Z/M \mathbf Z.$$ Hence, $U^L = U$.

Comment: I am sorry that I do not learn about abstract algebra. I heard of this formula $Lr+Ms=1$. Is this the key formula?  Anyway thanks for your answer!

Comment: @standerQiu  No problem! I've edited it including an outline that does not require the language of groups. It is mostly the $Lr + Ms = 1$ idea to conclude that the first set is contained in the second one. The result then follows from comparing their sizes :-)

Comment: Your answer helps me a lot! I understand how to prove now. Thank you!